# How to create a file in library document sharepoint by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to create a csv file in library document sharepoint by using Powershell v7

what I try:

```
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword 

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred 

$fileName = "YourFileName.txt"
$fileContent = "This is the content of the file."

# Get the root folder of the document library
$rootFolder = Get-PnPSite | Get-PnPRootFolder

# Upload the file to the document library
Add-PnPFile -Folder $rootFolder -FileName $fileName -Stream ([System.IO.MemoryStream]::new([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($fileContent)))

# Get the newly uploaded file
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url "/$documentLibraryName/$fileName"

# Get the associated list item
$listItem = $file.ListItemAllFields

# Update the file properties
Set-PnPListItem -List $documentLibraryName -Identity $listItem -Values @{"Title" = "YourFileTitle"; "Description" = "YourFileDescription"}
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: Do you have any error? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
# Provide credentials over here
$creds = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "username",(ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force))
 
# If you do not wish to pass credentials hard coded then you can use: -Credentials (Get-Credential). This will prompt to enter credentials
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yousite url -Credentials $creds


 
# Content for the CSV file (Modify as needed)
$CSVContent = @"
Column1,Column2,Column3
Value1,Value2,Value3
Value4,Value5,Value6
Value7,Value8,Value9
"@

# Get the document library where you want to upload the CSV file
$DocumentLibraryName = "your Shared Documents name"
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $DocumentLibraryName

# Convert the CSV content to a byte array
$CSVBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($CSVContent)

# Create a MemoryStream from the byte array
$CSVMemoryStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$CSVMemoryStream.Write($CSVBytes, 0, $CSVBytes.Length)

# Prepare the hashtable for the file upload
$fileContent = @{
    Stream = $CSVMemoryStream
    Folder = $List.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
    FileName = "YourFileName.csv"
}

# Upload the CSV content to the document library
Add-PnPFile @fileContent

# Disconnect from SharePoint Online
Disconnect-PnPOnline

Write-Host "CSV file created and uploaded successfully to the SharePoint document library."
```